# Fill Matrix by a part of another Matrix java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, matrix, size

I have a Matrix with different line size , i read it from a text file

private int set_data[][];

I have created another copy

```
private int set_number=set_data.length;
private int[][] set_cluster = new int[set_number][];
```

What i want to do is to fill set_cluster from the third row of each line

For example we have :

line one 1 3 30 49 48

line two 2 3 22 36 11 40

line three 3 5 51 44 47 15 38 40

and my goal is to store in set_cluster these numbers

line one 30 49 48

line two 22 36 11 40

line three 51 44 47 15 38 40

I have tried this code

```
    private void fill_id_cluster() {
    for (int i = 0; i < set_data.length; i++) {
        set_cluster[i] = new int[set_data[i].length - 2];
        for (int j = 0; j < set_data[i].length - 2; j++) {
            set_cluster[i][j] = set_data[i][j + 2] ;
            System.out.print(set_cluster[i][j] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So what's wrong? Does your program error out or simply give incorrect values?

Comment: I got an exceptionException in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Comment: What line was the error on? FYI when you post on here you should always include any error you got and if so you should point out where the error is in your code

Comment: this line    set_cluster[i] = new int[set_data[i].length - 2];

Comment: Because in each line we need to declare the number of row

Comment: Are you sure that set_data has been created properly?  ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 means that the 0th index of an array was accessed but said array doesn't have any elements.  This could mean that set_cluster is empty, or it could mean set_data is empty

Comment: An easy way to check is just to add System.out.println(set_data[0][0]); to the beginning of the function, if the program crashes on that line it means set_data is empty, if it doesn't and actually prints a value, it means set_cluster is empty

Comment: If the length of 'set_data[i].length' value is less than 2, that line will try to create array with negative length.

Comment: @Sreejith would that give IndexOutOfBounds: 0?

Comment: @Nerdsie I think, in that situation it will throw a ' java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException '.

Comment: @Sreejith i got this exception        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Comment: @Nerdsie I have tried the same function  without -2 , the idea is when we don't know the number of row in each line , and in each iteration we take the number of row from the original matrix

Comment: @houssem In your scenario, will there be any line with less than 2 numbers? If so how the is it required to create ' set_cluster ' against that line. Or we need to create 0 size array will empty value?

Comment: I don't think the -2 is the issue, I think your set_data isn't being setup.  Are you sure set_data actually contains data at the time this function is called? If so, are you sure that set_cluster has been initialized?

Comment: @houssem-houssem Yeah I also think so, please check you have initialized 'set_cluster' before the statement  'set_cluster[i] = new int[set_data[i].length - 2];' .  ie ' int[][] set_cluster = new int[set_data.length][]; '

Comment: @ Sreejith @ Nerdsie my mistake was i didn't give a value to set_number , i am sorry